# Real Time Notification

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, triggers, notifications

I want to show notification into admin panel if any user insert a new ticket. that means if a new row inserted into ticket table then on admin panel show a notification and ticket count will be increased.

I cant understand How to do it. if any example available of laravel or CI or PHP then please share.

I am using laravel 4.2

Comment: its called  push notifications, now you have head start just learn how it works. also  i would suggest you to do this with http://www.nodejs.org/ and http://socket.io/ because php is not best choice for this